react application not sending succesfull APi's call to node application in ohio university network
I have a react and a node application that are deployed with aws ec2. Everything works just fine with a regular internet connection, however when i try to use the application with the canadian ohio university network, every request sent to the node js application returns the error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. My question is how to remedy to this problem, as my application is destined to university students and i need the application to work on every internet network?

May I know do you use SSL/HTTPS when connecting to the server? If not, I am assuming your university network might have blocked unsafe networks. Try to use a service like Cloudflare to host your service and your user will access via Cloudflare nodes together with the benefit of HTTPS connection.

Yes i'm using ssl/htttps

I found about the problem, i just had to change the port in which the node js application is running from 3001 to 8080.
